# Does it make a difference in efficiency where variables are declared in Visual BASIC .net?

Tags: vb.net

In this code snippet for a vb.net Function, is it more efficient to declare variables at point A or point B?

I realize that this could be programmed without declaring x and y:  Return x + GetY() + GetZ(), but that is not the answer I'm looking for.

```
Private Function Sum(ByVal x As Integer)

    Dim y As Integer      ' A) declare variables here?
    Dim z As Integer

    If x <> 0 Then

      'Dim y As Integer   'B) or declare variables here?
      'Dim z As Integer

       y = GetY()
       z = GetZ()

       Return x + y + z

     Else Return x

     End If

End Function
```

Comment: The IL is the same. All the variables are initialized in `.locals init()` (before anything else). If that's what you're referring to.

Comment: It does not matter at all, statement scope does not exist after the compiler is done with it.  I suspect that most programmers prefer `Dim y = GetY() `, type inference is nice feature.

Comment: It makes no difference to how the code executes so it's a matter of style and good practice. Some people declare all locals at the top of a method while, these days, it's more common to declare them with the minimum scope possible, i.e. if they're only used inside a block then declare them inside that block. You might still declare them at the top of that block or only when they are used. Personally, I declare variables as late as possible. Doing so reduces the possibility that they will be used where they shouldn't.